# Google Drive API: search for all the files that I can edit, including those in shared drives

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I think the title is pretty explicit. I've read and read (and read) the [search files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files) doc, without success.

The problem is when I try to list the files that I can edit because I'm a contributor or manager of the shared drive they're located in: I have no direct permission on the files, I can edit them thanks to the inheritance.

I've tried to run the [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) request with `q = 'myadress' in writers or 'myadress' in owners` and it returns all the files I can edit except the case described above.

(Yes I set all the options relative to shared drive to true).

Are included in this search:

- the files in a "regular" drive that I can edit
- the files in a shared drive when I have an explicit "writer" permission on the file

Are excluded:

- the files that I can edit because they're in a shared drive I'm manager of (or contributor)

Is there any way to get all those files in one shot?

**edit**: to make it clear, I'm only interested in the files that I can edit. I could list all the files visible to me, and then check in the response object if I can edit them or not, but that would mean listing way more files than necessary.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

### You are right, that's not possible

I believe I have similar results to you:

#### The `q` parameter

[Search query terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms)

> To search for files, use the `q` parameter in files: files.list.

In the article cited above, there are many parameters for files in your main drive, for example: `writers`, `owners`, `readers`.

Yet if I made any request with a query containing `in writers` or `in owners`, if I could edit a file *only because I was a member of the parent shared drive* then it would not show up. It would only show up if someone had gone into the individual document and given me edit permission.

I could use other `q` parameters such as `fullText` and that would return shared drive items no problem.

**UPDATE**: It seems Google are aware of this issue now, https://issuetracker.google.com/171363628. Go and put a ☆ on it to let them know it affects you.

---

### Possible workarounds

You probably know these well, but I'll list them anyway for the benefit of future users.

#### Limit the fields

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/fields-parameter)

For example, using a request with the following parameters:

```
corpora = allDrives
includeItemsFromAllDrives = true
pageSize = 1000
supportsAllDrives = true
fields = files/id, files/name, files/capabilities/canEdit
key = [YOUR_API_KEY]
```

Which involves greatly limiting the fields returned for better performance and efficiency. In this case, only the id, name and a boolean for whether the user can edit are returned. In this request the `pageSize` is set to the maximum allowed.

Once you have this response, you could filter it in memory. As you suggested.

#### Make a few requests

I am not sure if you are running into quota issues, in which case, this option may not be practical for you.

If you are not averse to making *a few* calls to the API, is to identify the shared drives you have edit access to. **By necessity** you will have [edit access on the files contained therein](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-shareddrives#permission_propagation). Once you have identified the whether you can edit a certain shared drive. You can make a request of each shared drive and your main drive. Which depending on how many shared drives you have and how often they change, could be practical enough for you.

If the shared drives don't change very often at all, you could just keep a list of the shared drive IDs, which you could update periodically with an automatic script. So you are making one less request.

Comment: Hello @iansedano yes I confirm that I was able to list all files where I have an explicit  "writer" permission on it, whether they're in a regular Drive or in a shared Drive. Probably because no matter where the document is, there is still a "writers" array in the response. Of course you need to add `'your_adress' in writers` in the query.

Comment: Strange, I am not able to reproduce that, have tried many times. You are right that there is a "writers" array in all docs, but the query system works differently and at least on the API explorer, doesn't return any results from shared drive with your query. Where are you making your request from?

Comment: if you do a simple GET on this document only (`files.get`), you can see yourself in the `writers` array ?

Comment: No, for example, in a file I created, in a shared drive I also created, there is no `writers` array, there is a `permissionId` array. If I do a GET on the permission itself, there is no `writers` array either just a `permissionDetails` which lists me as a `member` and `organizer`. Actually, in a normal file in my normal drive, there is no `writers` array either, just a `permissions` one. This is why I say that the `q` parameter works in a different way.